# Who is 'Yehuda' in Yermiah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yirmiyahu--book-of

In [Yermiah 3:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.3.10?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) it says:

> וְגַם־בְּכָל־זֹ֗את לֹא־שָׁ֨בָה אֵלַ֜י בָּגוֹדָ֧ה אֲחוֹתָ֛הּ **יְהוּדָ֖ה** בְּכָל־לִבָּ֑הּ כִּ֥י אִם־בְּשֶׁ֖קֶר נְאֻם־יְהוָֽה

Yehuda is referred to as the sister of Israel. Who is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. From the time of R'chavam ben Shlomo, there were two Jewish nations: Yisrael in the North and Yehudah in the South. See Sefer Melochim.